# Mousedown and mousemove perform inconsistently in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an one page app in Meteor.

I want to track when whether a bookmarklet (in the form of a `<a>` tag containing an image) has been dragged towards the bookmarks bar.

I'm using a combination of mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup to try to track the drag.

```
Template.myTemplate.events = {  
  'mousedown': function(){    
    Session.set('dragging', true)   
    console.log('drag starts')
  },  
  'mouseup': function(){  
    if (Session.get('dragging') == true && event.y < 10){   
      // The result i want  
    }  
    Session.set('dragging', false)  
    console.log('drag stops')  
  }  
}
```

The drag starts well enough, but soon after the mouse leaves the `<a>` tag it just seems to baulk, and `mouseup` doesn't register as it should.

The logic works as it should if I `return false` after `mouseup` and `mousedown` - ie. I can move the mouse far and wide after mousedown, and watch for `event.y` being < 10 and there's no baulk - but then the code does not have the desired effect of the user being able to drag the `<a>` tag.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
'mousedown': function(){
```

You're doing mousedown on the template, it should be  on the `a` element.

So, do this instead:

```
'mousedown a': function(){
```

Or choose the right `a` element here.

Comment: I've tried that. No luck, sadly. Mousedown always works. It's mouseup that's the problem. It just seems to be very random whether it fires. In a non-Meteor setting, this: `$('#draggable').on('drag', function(event) {
    console.log(window.event.clientY);
   })` works fine.

Comment: In my experiments, mouseup seems to work only when the mouse isn't dragged. If it's dragged, only mousedown fires.

Comment: worth noting, for anyone passing, this is not a meteor problem but a general javascript issue - if the mouse leaves the element of the mousedown event, the mouseup event is not fired... have a general template level (or even body) mouseup event see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019190/mouseup-event-on-drag)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay, but i could only see now kk

But you can get your event data from the bank with `mousedown` (I believe you already do that), and add the `mousemove` where you want to drop your event. It's not quite the right way to implement it, but it can solve